# Apple News API formatting with Chapter three in PHP

Tags: php, html, json, api, formatting

I have to make JSON like this as accepted by Apple news format.

```
    {
  "version": "1.7",
  "identifier": "SampleArticle",
  "language": "en",
  "title": "Apple News App",
  "subtitle": "A look at the features of the News iOS app",
  "layout": {
    "columns": 20,
    "width": 1024,
    "margin": 60,
    "gutter": 20
  },
  "components": [
    {
      "role": "title",
      "text": "Apple News App",
      "textStyle": "title"
    },
    {
      "role": "body",
      "text": "The Apple News Format allows publishers to craft beautiful editorial layouts. Galleries, audio, video, and fun interactions like animation make stories spring to life."
    },
    {
      "role": "photo",
      "URL": "bundle://image.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "documentStyle": {
    "backgroundColor": "#F7F7F7"
  },
  "componentTextStyles": {
    "default": {
      "fontName": "Helvetica",
      "fontSize": 13,
      "linkStyle": {
        "textColor": "#428bca"
      }
    },
    "title": {
      "fontName": "Helvetica-Bold",
      "fontSize": 30,
      "hyphenation": false
    },
    "default-body": {
      "fontName": "Helvetica",
      "fontSize": 13
    }
  }
}
```

What I've tried so far is
Apple news Chapter three
[formating and publishing Apple news API PHP class](https://github.com/chapter-three/AppleNewsAPI)
documentation here
[Documenmtnion  for chapter three Apple news API](http://chapter-three.github.io/AppleNewsAPI/namespaces/default.html)

[Link for the Detailed document for what i've tried and out put](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1in8K33MASv42qhVWgpDrSPanI8VrqQAT/view?usp=sharing)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Components\Body;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Layouts\Layout;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Styles\ComponentTextStyle;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Base;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Styles\Text;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Styles\ComponentTextStyleTest;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Styles\InlineTextStyle;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Styles\Border;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Styles\TextStyle;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Components;
```

used this class to get the formating in the html content. It should have to return a JSON Format. I've shared earlier but it returns the styling only, not the Text. Sometimes empty JSON formats.

```
$articleBody = '<p style="font-size:13;border-top:1px;text-align:center">A quick brown Fox jumps over the Alzy Dog</p>'; ## with inline styling tags
```

Example code come with the class

```
$title_id = uniqid();
$obj = new Document(uniqid(), $articleTitle, 'en', new Layout(7, 1024));
$obj->addComponent(new Body($articleBody))
     ->addComponentTextStyle('default', new ComponentTextStyle());
##that outputs only plain text in the right format. 
##but not the inline HTML content.
 <?php  # differnent object names for different function
$obj3 = new Body($articleBody);   
$obj3->getFormat();

$json = $obj3->json();
echo $json;
#also tried to get border 
$newobj = new Border(new Body($articleBody));
echo $newobj->getTop();
# and
$newobj2 = new InlineTextStyle(12,144,'center');
$newobj2-> getTextStyle(new Body($articleBody));
?>
#But none of them get me to actuall feed format. 
#Do anybody know any format or class which will convert HTML content. to #apple news format in PHP. 


$content = '<p><em>PopOff Marketing, a top-quality Search Engine Optimization and Search Engine Marketing Agency, is launching a new rebrand and website that is expected to be finished on October 12th! The agency specializes in a wide range of support and solutions tailored to specific business needs in this current competitive market. PopOff Marketing provides the best digital marketing services at affordable prices to help your business literally pop off!</em></p>
<p><em>FOR IMMEDIATE RELEASE</em></p>


<a href="https://www.popoffmarketing.com/about/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">https://www.popoffmarketing.com/about/</a>.</p>
<p><strong>Contact Info:</strong></p>
<p>Chris Corigliano<br />
PopOff Marketing<br />
8660 Homeplace Dr.<br />
Office: (844) 934-0590</p>
<div id="fd7209aa303fa1c07bb197a83d101b48" class="trk"><img loading="lazy" class="aligncenter" src="https://demo.popoffmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/PM-Logo-Big-Prints.png" alt="PopOff Marketing" width="250" height="250" /></div>
<div></div>
<div><em>Originally Posted On: <a href="https://syndication.cloud/popoff-marketing-pops-off-their-newest-rebrand-to-launch-october-12th/">https://syndication.cloud/popoff-marketing-pops-off-their-newest-rebrand-to-launch-october-12th/</a></em></div>';
```

***How does this content(feed) converted to JSON Format given on the top of the question?***

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `Markdown` class to get that converted into a component.

Something like this should work:

```
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Markdown;
use ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Components\Body;

$markdown = new Markdown();
$text = $markdown->convert('YOUR HTML CODE GOES INTO HERE');
$body = new Body($text, 'give-some-unique-id');
$body->setFormat('markdown');
$document->addComponent($body);
```